# Get clinics where item equal one of element in list in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need the equivalent Entity Framework query for this code:

```
List<Clinic> clinics = ClinicDAL.ReadClinics(uid).ToList();

List<Service> obj = new List<Service>();

foreach (var item in clinics)
{
   var services = dbContext.Services.Where(a => a.ClinicID == item.ID).ToList();
   obj.AddRange(services);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that code not using Entity Framework already? It's not at all clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Contains operator:

```
var clinicIDs = clinics.Select(c => c.ID).ToArray();
var services = dbContext.Services.Where(a => clinicIDs.Contains(a.ClinicID)).ToList();
```